# Maven project as Playframework dependancy

Tags: java, maven, playframework

I'm working on a project using Maven as tool. Within the project I have a toy-server to test in a web environment the output of the project, so that the structure is like this:

```
src
   main
       java
           my_namespace
                       testserver
                                 server_class1
                                 server_class2
                       projectclass1
                       projectclass2
                       projectclass3
```

As the project grows, I'd like to use Play Framework to build a better web-testing environment. I've read that Play and Maven don't work well together, so eventually I'll create a second project (Play) with a dependancy on a jar generated by Maven in the current project.

How to synch the two projects?

In Play external dependancies have to be found in the /lib directory. Since I'll work at both the projects at the same time, I need a way to tell Maven that, when done packing the jar, it has to be copied into an external directory (Play's /lib). Or I need Play to pick the jar from a non standard position.

Again, since my project has some dependancies, would they be resolved within the jar if used in a non-maven environment? Do I need to create a uber-jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, play dependencies do not need to be copied to the lib folder by yourself : your can use the dependencies system integrated in Play!.

Check this : [Play! dependencies](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/dependency).

The command

```
play deps
```

will retrieve the dependencies of your Java project.